# I've got when run command "set GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 4294967295" in cpanel

Tags: mysql, cpanel

When I tried to do

```
set GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 4294967295
```

in cpanel, I get the error

> ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: Remember, you are probably sharing a MySQL Instance on this hosting package, so you will not be allowed to amend anything GLOBAL as it could effect the 100 other packages sharing the server

Comment: Why you try to set global setting? set session one. Maybe as additional command in connection properties.

Comment: @Akina i want want to do this because i used GROUP_CONCAT() but not return all data

Comment: *i want want to do this because i used GROUP_CONCAT() but not return all data* Set SESSION variable, not GLOBAL.

Answer (score 1):

The command to give the permission (on your database) should be something like this:
GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwordName';

But like @RiggsFolly and @Akina said, check the need in doing this.